# How to create a small and simple sql without using case

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is my view sql command. I want to make it small without using case.

```
select a.nrc_typ_cd,a.nrc_typ_nm,a.a as "No of IMIS Source",b.b as "No of New Source",c.c as "No of Source Marked Bad",d.d as "No of Source with Lat/Long",e.e as "No of Source without Lat/Long" from
(select nrc_typ_cd,nrc_typ_nm,count(nrc_cd) as a from tableview_dtl  where imis_nrc_cd is not null and act_flg='A' group by nrc_typ_cd,nrc_typ_nm ) a,
(select nrc_typ_cd,count(nvl(nrc_cd,0)) as b from tableview_dtl  where imis_nrc_cd is null and act_flg='A' group by nrc_typ_cd ) b,
(select nrc_typ_cd,count(nrc_cd) as c from tableview_dtl   where act_flg='I' group by nrc_typ_cd ) c,
(select nrc_typ_cd,count(nrc_cd) as d from tableview_dtl   where lat_val_degree is not null and long_val_degree is not null and act_flg='A' group by nrc_typ_cd) d,
(select nrc_typ_cd,count(nvl(nrc_cd,0)) as e from tableview_dtl   where lat_val_degree is null and long_val_degree is null and act_flg='A' group by nrc_typ_cd) e
where a.nrc_typ_cd=b.nrc_typ_cd
and  a.nrc_typ_cd=c.nrc_typ_cd
and  a.nrc_typ_cd=d.nrc_typ_cd
and  a.nrc_typ_cd=e.nrc_typ_cd
order by a.nrc_typ_cd
```

Comment: You have no case in it why can't you use it as it is?

Comment: @PresidentCamacho this instruction is given by my PL.I have already made this code using case but it is not acceptable.Sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

(This is more of an extended comment than an answer.)

So this is the version of the code that you *don't* want?

```
select nrc_typ_cd,nrc_typ_nm
    ,count(case when imis_nrc_cd is not null and act_flg='A' then nrc_cd else null end) a
    ,count(case when imis_nrc_cd is not null and act_flg='A' then nvl(nrc_cd, 0) else null end) b
    ,count(case when act_flg='I' then nrc_cd else null end) c
    ,count(case when lat_val_degree is not null and long_val_degree is not null and act_flg='A' then nrc_cd else null end) d,
    ,count(case when lat_val_degree is null and long_val_degree is null and act_flg='A' then nvl(nrc_cd, 0) else null end) e,
from tableview_dtl
group by nrc_typ_cd,nrc_typ_nm
order by a.nrc_typ_cd;
```

It seems simpler, shorter, and faster than the newer version.  It's important to *fully* explain why this obvious solution is insufficient before
 people can reasonably propose alternatives.

According to a comment, this version is not acceptable because "instruction is given by my PL".  (What does "PL" mean; project lead?)  What does the PL have
 against `CASE`?  I can't think of a good reason to ask someone to rewrite something to avoid a `CASE`.

Would it be enough to use a `DECODE` instead?  Or does the entire query need to be re-written?

Comment: We face more problem when we Add "CASE" using sql into the Dao.

Comment: Maybe this is more a question about the DAO then SQL then?  Can you add some information and tags about the product you're using?

Comment: thanks for your valuable time on this question.As you have ask me for case and decode.                                                                                        //case is not satisfy sometime for loop
//decode is not take "is not null".means it not take void space.Basically I face this problem in my code.

Comment: DECODE handles NULLs differently than other parts of Oracle.  From [the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions057.htm#SQLRF00631): "In a DECODE function, Oracle considers two nulls to be equivalent. If expr is null, then Oracle returns the result of the first search that is also null."

Comment: @Jhon Heller When I am using decode in my sql it send error